# escape single quote within yaml file

Tags: awk, sed, yaml

How can i escape a single quote within yaml for the following statements. Basically for the awk and sed expressions below ??

```
...
    command: ['sh', '-c']
    args: ['
        awk -F"\t" '{print $1}' ....
        sed \\'s/\"//g\\' ....
                    ']
```

So a minimal exemple like below

```
command: ['sh', '-c']
args: ['
          echo " Single quote is '  "
          ']
will fail with error: error parsing exemple.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Comment: Not clear, please do provide more details in your post about your question and let us know then.

Comment: Is it relevant that they are awk and sed commands? Does it work for a simplified version, say, `args: ['a b ' c']`?

Comment: awk and sed are not relevant i guess, added a minimal exemple in the code

Comment: The cause of this specific error is unrelated to the quotes or escaping. The problem is that you've indented `args:` deeper than `command:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct cause of your error is that `args:` is indented farther to the right than `command:`. Assuming you want `command:` and `args:` to both be keys of the same mapping, they need to have the same indentation.

As for how to escape inner quotes in YAML, the easiest solution is **don't**.

In your YAML you're using a **flow style sequence** (`[ … ]`) with one item, a **flow style scalar** (string) wrapped in quotes (`'…'`). To avoid escaping issues, switch to a **block style sequence** and **literal block style scalar**:

```
command: [sh, -c]
args:
  - |
    awk -F"\t" '{print $1}' ...
    sed 's/"//g' ...
```

In the above YAML the value corresponding to the `args` key is still a sequence with a single item but it uses the block style, in which each item is preceded by `-`. The `|` indicates [**literal style**](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id928806), meaning the lines that follow (and having the same or greater indentation as the first one) are all a single scalar and that line breaks should be preserved.

You can see how this YAML will be parsed—and that the string's multiple lines and inner quotes are correctly preserved—in the below snippet.

```js
const yaml = `
command: [sh, -c]
args:
  - |
    awk -F"\t" '{print $1}' ...
    sed 's/"//g' ...
`;

const data = jsyaml.safeLoad(yaml);

console.log(data);
console.log(data.args[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-yaml/3.13.1/js-yaml.min.js"></script>
```